# Input argument "ip" is undefined Error

Tags: matlab

I am new in matlab I am trying to define a function and I keep getting this error

" input argument "ip" is undefined.

Error in ==> edge_mapping at 2
size_ip = size(ip(:,:,1)); "

here is my code

```
    function[op1,op2,op3] = edge_mapping(ip)
size_ip = size(ip(:,:,1));
s=size_ip(1);
op1= cat(3,zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s));
op2= cat(3,zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s));
op3= cat(3,zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s),zeros(s));
for i = 1 : 10
    op1(:,:,i)=edge(ip(:,:,i),'sobel');
    op2(:,:,i)=edge(ip(:,:,i),'prewitt');
    op3(:,:,i)=edge(ip(:,:,i),'canny');
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're repeatedly concatenating `zeros(s)` 10 times, instead of doing something like `zeros(s*10,s)`? Similarly, you are initialising `op1, op2, op3` to be the same matrix to start with - why repeat the definition three times? Define `op1` and then make copies, `op2 = op1; op3 = op1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function [op1, op2, op3] = edge_mapping(ip)
op1 = zeros(size(ip));
op2 = zeros(size(ip));
op3 = zeros(size(ip));
for i = 1 : size(ip, 3)
    op1(:,:,i)=edge(ip(:,:,i),'sobel');
    op2(:,:,i)=edge(ip(:,:,i),'prewitt');
    op3(:,:,i)=edge(ip(:,:,i),'canny');
end
return
```

But I think it's better to write a simple function:

```
function op = edge_mapping(ip, edge_mode)
op = zeros(size(ip));
for i = 1 : size(ip, 3)
    op(:,:,i)=edge(ip(:,:,i), edge_mode);
end
return
```

and then call it:

```
op_sobel = edge_mapping(ip, 'sobel');
op_prewitt = edge_mapping(ip, 'prewitt');
op_canny = edge_mapping(ip, 'canny');
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is a function. It has to be save as m-file and run from MATLAB command line, script or another function as

```
[op1,op2,op3] = edge_mapping(ip);
```

where arguments ip, op1, op2, and op3 can have different names.

Make sure you have space after `function` keyword.

To avoid this error you can assign a default value for the input argument if it's undefined (not exist in the function's scope):

```
if ~exist(ip, 'var')
    ip = []; %# or other default value
end
```